# Or command not doing what I'd expect it to

Tags: python

```
print ("In this game your choice will affect the outcome of the story.")
input ("Press Enter to continue...")
print(" ")
print ("You wake up one morning but something seems odd...")
print ("You realise that you are not in your bed!")
print ("You have the choice to leave this unknown house straight away or stay, to find out whose house it is.")
input ("Press Enter to continue...")
FirstBranch = str(input ("Press L to leave or S to stay "))
if FirstBranch == ("L") or ("l"):
    print ("You leave the house, wearing only a pair of jeans and a T-shirt. ")
    input ("Press Enter to continue...")
    print ("Once you call a cab, you check your phone and realise that last night you were meant to be babysitting your sister! ")
    print ("What happened? This isn't like you.  ")
    print("You think about returning to the house that you woke up in to find more answers. ")
    input ("Press Enter to continue...")
    FirstBranchOne = str(input("Press G to go back to the house or H to go home. "))
    if FirstBranchOne == ("H") or ("h"):
        print("You decide to go home. ")
        input("Press Enter to continue... ")
        print("Once you arrive home, you open the front door and overhear your family talking about you in the kitchen... ")
        print("You listen closely to what they say and gather that your parents came home earlier than expected last night and they let you go to a party...")
        input("Press Enter to continue... ")
        print("However, they seem worried, as you were not home when they woke up. ")
    else:
        print("You tell your taxi driver to drop you off where he picked you up. ")
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
        print("As you walk to the door you see a bright flash and then hear a loud bang from a tube station nearby.")
        FirstBranchTwo = str(input("Press E to investigate the explosion or H to investigate the house "))
        if FirstBranchTwo == ("H") or ("h"):
            print("You enter the house - the door was left unlocked - and see that one of the doors inside is ajar. ")
            print("You take a peek inside and realise it leads down to the basement. ")
        else:
            print("You run across the road to the tube station which is now surrounded by emergency services.")

else:
    print ("You stay in the house and decide to investigate. ")
```

Why is it that when I press l to leave house it works fine but in the next branch it makes no difference if I press G or H, it just gives me the same result? (This is Python 3)

Comment: By the way this is python 3 not python 2 so raw_input doesn't work in this does it?

Comment: Right, `input()` in Python 3 is what you need.  It's the same as what was called `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Comment: @EpicDude that's correct, don't be fooled by these high-rep users, sometimes you know better ;) But the duplicate target should answer your actual problems.